# cells of a matrix recursion

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to make a kind of a game, it receives from a text file the size of the array and how will the cells of mesmo.

O game is to see if there is a path in the matrix through the matrix cells, it gives the first line until the last line.

Here's an example: input (file): 5

```
true   false   true  false  false
true   false  true   true   true
false  false  false  false  true
true   true   false   true   true
false  false  false  true    false
```

- `* = True`
- `- = False`

The matrix is:

```
* - * - -
* - * * *
- - - - *
* * - * *
- - - * -
```

and I want to appear at the end:

```
- - * - -
- - * * *
- - - - *
- - - * *
- - - * -
```

I have Constructs the initial matrix, one that is made from the text file, just can not make print the final array with the path, if it exists.

Comment: Your 'true/false' map does not match the second matrix with */-, check the 1st and the 4th row

Comment: done,i'm sorry for that